# Debug a Blazor WebAssembly demo with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a new hosted Blazor WebAssembly project with dotnet cli without modifying any files, I opened the project with Visual Studio Code and it asks me to add files for debugging. I pressed Yes and two .json files are created in the .vscode directory.
Why am I getting a message saying "Browser cannot start ..." when I start the project with F5 and the debug doesn't work?
I have already tried to follow the official documentation but the debugger does not work. I have installed C # Debugging Extension and Blazor WebAssembly with no success.
Thank you.

PS. I'm sorry for my english. :-)

Comment: Hey Marco, what version of net core and Visual Studio are you using ? The debug in blazor-webassembly only work from net core 6...

Comment: I use last .NET 6 and last Visual Studio Code. With Visual Studio 2022 community the debugger works fine

Comment: You can provide more details of which project is set to start and which code stretch you want to debug ?

Comment: I'm sorry, now that I realized that you are trying to use Vscode.
Have you tried to follow this documentation?
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for replies. Yes I tried.

Comment: @Mårshåll I have set as startup project the "server project". I would debug the client pages.

Comment: I solved it, the problem was in the project configuration files in VS Code that were created outside the project folder (by VS Code). Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @MarcoSantoni I also had this problem. I found a workaround, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037574) for working config.